# Error building project with added static library

Tags: ios, static-libraries

When i run my project, i have errors, this project includes static library.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Composer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libImageCollage_Simulator.a(ImageCollageTableViewController.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FirstTableViewCell", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libImageCollage_Simulator.a(ImageCollageTableViewController.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SecondTableViewCell", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libImageCollage_Simulator.a(ImageCollageTableViewController.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ThirdTableViewCell", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libImageCollage_Simulator.a(ImageCollageTableViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What can i do?

Comment: Have you added the library to your user search paths?

Answer (score 0):

Your Project was linked with Static Library, You havent added `libImageCollage_Simulator.a` Library in the Project, To add that Go to Build Phases in Project Settings, in Target Dependencies click `+` and add the library to your project [image]

Also Add Library Search Path here like this [image]
Go to Build Phases and Double Click Library Search Paths, click plus and add the path of the library in your project

Comment: When i click + in Target Dependencies i haven't library in list.

Comment: Then how did you includes static library. It will be like `libraryname.a`

Comment: I copied library and header file into project folder and add it. Xcode automatically add library in "Link Binary With Libraries"

Comment: Did you seen any library in `Target dependencies`

Comment: When i make simple library and add it in project, it works ok. But now, when i make library with many files it doesn't work.